# Ellipsize NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to ellipsize the text content of an NSTextField, instead of truncate?

So instead of:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over
```

It would say:

```
The quick brown fox jumped ...
```

I can't find anything in the documentation for this. What am I missing?

UPDATE:
Is there any way to ellipsize AND wordwrap--in other words, have multiple lines and ellipsize the last?

Comment: I thought selecting truncate or `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` does the ellipses automatically -

Comment: Chad, if you gave me the bounty thank you and now I feel bad as I didn't really answer your question. Someone dinged me this am (downvoted the answer), so funny I just relooked at the question and your update. I do have a suggestion for you and will edit my answer now.

Comment: No problem, @DavidH! You answered the question as originally asked--I had neglected to include the "ellipsize AND wordwrap" part that made the question difficult. And you're welcome on the bounty--thank you for the thoughts you added!

Comment: If you want to try coding the suggestion - if that looks good to you - will be glad to assist as needed.

Comment: `lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is a great question! Even though its exposed in IB, its not a property on the view or any subview. Instead its buried as a property on the cell used by NSTextField. So if you ask that object for its cell, you can then read or set the value: lineBreakMode.

Look in the class description for NSCell for all the options - truncateCenter is one (to get center ellipsis).

EDIT: the following thoughts were prompted by the updated question. Personally, I think trying to get that google code is way overkill and perhaps you can do something less complex by creating a mini-custom textField.

- create a customer NSView object and give it a string and font property and some methods related to the actions below, and perhaps even a width property
- essentially the idea is to use the Cocoa NSString category that lets you determine the length of string (and probably its height) from a string/font combo (I use this in UIKit, did use equivalents in Cocoa, but its been a while...)
- one of your view's methods will be 'calculate'. When you get this, covert the string to an array of words using a single space as the separator (or make it more complex). Then, start computing the length of the drawn string, taking the first work, append a space and the second, etc, until you find you have exceeded he width. This is your first line string.
- continue doing this for the number of lines that you want to draw (2? 3?). Calculate the length of the unicode char that does ... - its option semicolon as I recall - and keep that around.
- in the last line, keep adding words until you exceed the length, and then back up a word at a time, verifying that the last appended strings string (minus a trailing space) but with the '...' char will fit in the space.
- you can make this fancier by adding padding around the border etc.
- once the calculation is finished (and you of course cache all the bits of the answer), your view is prepared when it gets 'drawRect:...'. You position at (0, bounds.size.height - 21) and draw the first segment, then move down 21 points and draw the second line, etc.

If I were to code this I would plan on 2-4 hours - its not trivial, perhaps the logic is a bit complex, but its straightforward. Good luck!

Comment: Right - I updated my text to reflect my typo - thanks and an up arrow :-)

Comment: Looks great, David--but the "truncate" options force the NSTextField to only one line. Is there a way to make the NSTextField ellipsize and wordwrap?

Comment: Sorry don't know of anyway to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Although the correct answer was not accepted in this old question - scroll to the last answer - it includes the code [Truncate the last line of multi-line NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138786/truncate-the-last-line-of-multi-line-nstextfield/11721872#11721872)

The solution includes the use of ellipses and line wrapping combined.