# Render multi line centered text similar Icon View in OS X Finder

Tags: macos, text, finder

How do I render multi-line centered text, limited to a specific frame size, along with inserting the … (ellipsis) char when the text doesn't fit?

Background:

I am developing a custom view that mimicks OS X Finder's "as Icons" view, with the Label position set to "Bottom". In this view mode, file names appear below icons in two rows, like this (with ASCII art for the bounding frame):

```
+------------------------+
|  long file name that   |
| gets centered…rest.jpg |
+------------------------+
```

I understand that an NSTextField can almost accomplish that, but not completely: With the settings "Wrap" and "Truncate Last Visible Line" (as offered in Xcode's IB), it ends up like this:

```
+------------------------+
|  long file name that   |
| gets centered and mor… |
+------------------------+
```

I.e, it truncates the text at the end and not in the middle of the last visible line.

Also, I cannot use a NSControl but need to render the text into a graphics context instead.

Is there any framework function that can do this, or is this code private to the Finder and I'll need to rewrite all that myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138786/truncate-the-last-line-of-multi-line-nstextfield .  The accepted answer there talks about `NSTextField`, but I doubt that you'd really need a control.  Note that `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` can be used in a paragraph style in an attributed string.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks! I recognize your name, too. Alias Dragon FTW! :)

Comment: You have a good memory, I can barely remember Alias Dragon.

Comment: The linked code had issued which I have fixed now. I guess this question can be closed as a dupe, then.